# Software to group emails, tasks, notes, calendars under folders

Tags: productivity, information-management

I've scoured the Internet trying to find software that can do the following: in one interface, group emails, files, tasks, notes, and calendars into folders and sub-folders.

For example, I want to create a folder called 'Studies' and be able to see all emails, notes, tasks, lists, etc. under that folder.

I'm trying out [Toodledo](http://www.toodledo.com/) and it does provide the function of grouping tasks, lists, notes under folders, but it doesn't provide integration for email and calendar events.
If Outlook Express or Thunderbird have add-ons for these type of functions, that might suffice too.

I'd prefer a Ubuntu-based solution, but if none exists, then can consider a Windows solution.

Comment: I've tried Evolution on Lubuntu, and it does have functionality for reading email, calendar integration and tasks. However, their grouping metaphor is labels while I want folders. Still searching for the perfect one, but Evolution is certainly a best-of-the-rest candidate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through a lot of different web apps and software, I came across [Zoho](http://zoho.com). They provide free email, calendars, tasks, and notes. And they also include a separate suite for project management. And creating a folder or tag in tasks makes it available for notes. Also, events can be associated with tasks, and emails can also be associated with tasks. The association of emails and tasks isn't the most smooth, and the UI needs some improvements. Also, the folders in tasks and notes are not available in email, they have to be manually recreated. However, all in all, this is closest to the service/software I was looking for. It's also a lot better and more integrated than the Evolution software.